# Backend stack with microservice architecture

Tags: graphql, architecture, microservices, amazon-sqs

Currently I am migrating my CRM to microservice architecture. Is this arch suitable to be called solid and robust? (High loads are expected in future)

Main point of this architecture is one service - one db (as implied in microservices), so I decided that it will look smth like this. I want to mitigate all problems that might be in future before migration.

Here is api-gateway with graphql and subgraph for every services like: tasks, orders, clients etc. Subgraph will send queries to microservices and collect all data needed for response.

Wanted to ask from community if there are some mistakes or downsides of this architecture, or advices to make it better, so please point me if there is one.

[image]

Comment: Other technologies like s3, redis, dynamodb, etc. will be used later.

Answer (score 1):

> High loads are expected in future

I would argue that microservices are not exactly about performance per se. Arguably there are a lot of cases when monolithic approach is beneficial from squeezing out the most performance point of view (especially if you consider that in-process communication is faster than RPC).

For example:

- Stackoverflow itself is build with monolith architecture AFAIK - [Case Study: How Stackoverflow's monolith beats microservice performance.](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/case-study-how-stackoverflows-monolith-beats-navjot-bansal)
- Amazon Prime moving Microservices to Monolith - [The Prime Video Tech article](https://www.primevideotech.com/video-streaming/scaling-up-the-prime-video-audio-video-monitoring-service-and-reducing-costs-by-90):

  > The move from a distributed microservices architecture to a monolith application helped achieve higher scale, resilience, and reduce costs.

The main benefits of microservice architecture (IMHO):

- Organizational: when you have big team and/or very feature-rich application it can be highly beneficial to split an app into loosely coupled components which can be deployed separately.
- You have different performance and/or technology requirements for different parts of the system.

Few notes:

- Microservice architecture is highly sensitive to the service decomposition if it is done wrong you can easily end up with a [distributed monolith](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/distributed-monoliths-recognizing-addressing-luis-soares-m-sc-)
- In my experience duplication of data (i.e. service maintaining locally a "read-only" copy of data managed by other service) is quite important in microservice architecture from performance point of view
- [Eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency)

See more:

- [A pattern language for microservices](https://microservices.io/patterns/index.html)
- [Avoiding Microservice Megadisasters - Jimmy Bogard](https://youtu.be/gfh-VCTwMw8?si=Wtr-o8rlWD5_SR7u) (highly recommended)